# Which decision tree algorithm is used in randomForest in R?

Tags: r, random-forest, decision-tree

I would like to know, which implementation of random forest in package randomForest in R is used to grow decision trees? Is it CART, ID3, C4.5 ,...... or sth else?

Comment: CART-like trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `?randomForest()` the description states:

> **randomForest implements Breiman’s random forest algorithm** (based on
>   Breiman and Cutler’s original Fortran code) for classification and
>   regression. It can also be used in unsupervised mode for assessing
>   proximities among data points, with Breiman L (2001). "Random
>   Forests"." Based on:  Machine Learning. 45 (1): 5–32.
>   doi:10.1023/A:1010933404324.

According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest):

> **The introduction of random forests proper was first made in a paper
>   by Leo Breiman This paper describes a method of building a forest of
>   uncorrelated trees using a CART** like procedure. Reference to Breiman L (2001).
>   "Random Forests". Machine Learning. 45 (1): 5–32.
>   doi:10.1023/A:1010933404324. "

Therefore I would say ***it is CART***.

Answer (score 2):

In R, the `()randomForest` package is using CART. There is also another package in R called `()ranger` which can run decision trees at a faster pace